# Need a command sequence that will move files from one directory to another based on a particular year?

Tags: command-line, files, find

I'm looking for a sequence of commands (one liner would be ideal) which will identify all the files created in particular year, and move the resulting files to another directory.

Comment: _created_ (whatever that means), or _last modified_?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: What Unix variant?

Comment: @l0b0, not any more than 80% the questions asked here. ITYM that it was not asked in a way/tone that is respectful of the potential answerers, but in itself, it's an interesting question, not that easy to answer in a portable and reliable way.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - did you want to try and salvage this Q&A? I think there is a kernel of a good Q in there, we'll have to edit it of course. I'm torn b/c I do not like to do all the work for the OP's but I also like to fill our site with interesting/useful Q&A's.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I edited the Q to try and make it more suitable for the site. I don't think we need the variants to make it useful, though that would be nice to have.

Comment: Folks - Let's leave this one closed, there is a duplicate with a similar answer to boot.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU or FreeBSD `find` (and possibly others), and assuming you mean to search on the *last modification time*:

```
y=2001
find . -type f -newermt "$y-01-01" ! -newermt "$(($y+1))-01-01" -exec sh -c '
  exec mv "$@" /dest/dir' sh {} +
```

Note that it would not include a file that was last modified exactly at 00:00:00.000000 on 2001-01-01, but would include one last modified at that time on 2002-01-01.

Another option with GNU tools:

```
y=2001
find . -type f -printf '%TY%p\0' | sed -zn "s/^$y//p" | xargs -r0 mv -t /dest/dir
```

With `zsh`:

```
autoload age
y=2001
mv -- **/*(D.e:age $y/01/01 $((y+1))/01/01:) /dest/dir
```

GNU and FreeBSD `find` also support looking at the *birth* time, but note that that time refers to when the inode was spawn (link count went from 0 to 1), it doesn't reflect the age of the content, or when that file was available by that name in the directory it is linked to, and not all operating or file systems support a birth time or a way to query it (Linux still doesn't as of 2014-01).

Note that the answers above do not check for potential file name collisions (for instance, `./foo/x` and `./bar/x` would end up overwriting each other).

Answer (score 1):

edit: changed the timestamp of /tmp/begin, thanks to StephaneChazelas's comment

```
man touch #find how to create a "begin" file JUST BEFORE Jan 1st of the year at 00:00:00.000
          #and a "end" file for JUST AFTER the Dec 31st of the year, at 23:59:59.999
  #usually, -t time 
  #   specifies a particular time using this format:
  #        [[[[cc]yy]MM]dd]hhmm[.ss]

#make sure you place those 2 files OUTSIDE of the place where you look for files, as they are themselves suceptible to be moved!

touch -t 200901010000.00 /tmp/begin  #1st Jan of 2009 at 00h00mn00s (note: files with that exact time will be not included!)
touch -t 201001010000.00 /tmp/end    #just after Dec 31st of 2009

#then: with '/orig' the starting folder you want to look in, and '/dest' the destination folder:
find /orig \( \( -newer /tmp/begin \) -a \( ! -newer /tmp/end \) \) -exec echo mv '{}' /dest \;

#and remove "echo" once you know it's just listing the relevant files
```

Comment: Note that modern file systems have sub-second granularity, so newer(20081231235959) would include a whole second worth of files that shouldn't be included while newer(20090101000000) would exclude a microsecond worth of files that shouldn't be excluded.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: you're of course right, and it's good to warn about it... but it's easy to look for those files and see if they should be moved or not (before removing the "echo") ... And that's why I start the post with "man touch", as on the system I looked (an old AIX), `touch` only goes to the second ^^ ... (I believe the OS is more precise, though :/ So indeed the whole "touch" approach here may be flawed, or at least needs to be carefully looked at at the "edges"). The "echo" allows one to verify if this or that edge file is included or not, and adjust the "touch" accordingly.

Comment: What I meant is that you don't need the extra complexity, `touch -t 200901010000.00` would not be less correct. If you do `touch -t 200812312359.59 begin`, then why not `touch -t 200912312359.59 end`?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: ah ok, I understand. I'll indeed change that, as it's "less problematic" to just forget files specifically dated 0000.00, than to incorporate those made in the whole second before...

Answer (score 1):

this is one way of doing it:

```
src_dir=/tmp/in
target_dir=/tmp/out
year=2014

find ${src_dir} -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read f; do
  changed_in_desired_year=$(stat "$f" | egrep "Change:[ ]*${year}-")
  if [ -z "${changed_in_desired_year}" ]; then
    continue
  fi

  mv "$f" ${target_dir}
done
```

The interesting bit is the use of `stat` to get the changed/modified/access status of the file.

Comment: Note that `-maxdepth` is not a standard option to `find`.

Comment: You forgot the `-r` option to `read` (will break on filenames containing backslashes), and to remove the whitespace characters from IFS (will break on filenames ending in those)

Comment: Note that the `stat` command is not standard. There are several conflicting implementations.

Comment: You seem to be assuming GNU `stat` here. Note that GNU `find` has the features of `stat` builtin (with `-printf`). Your code will only work in some English locales. In Spanish locales, you'd see `Cambio:`... for instance.

Comment: find: bad option -maxdepth
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list

Comment: Why would you check the inode change time?

Comment: got the below edit while executing the above script

Comment: got the below edit while executing the above script 
find: bad option -maxdepth find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
 find . -type f -newerBt 2013-01-01 ! -newerBt 2014-01-01 | awk '{ print "mv " $0 " /dest/path/" }'
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158044/how-to-use-find-to-search-for-files-created-on-a-specific-date

Comment: `-newerct` checks the inode change time, it's not neither the file creation time or the age of the data as it is now in the file. Beare of what you do with the `awk` output. Don't pass it unchecked to `sh` as it could have dire consequences.

Comment: @Stéphane, I think the file is being checked. As man says: -newerXY file ; In addition, if Y=t, then file is instead interpreted as a direct date specification.

Comment: But the "c" is for inode _change_ time, not _creation_ (birth) time for which you need `-newerBt` (where available)

Comment: Agree :) Will fix it here.